# Check if object already exists?

Tags: object, prolog, exists, logtalk

i have :

```
:- use_module(library(logtalk)).
:- {buffer}.
:- initialization(main).

main :-
    create_object(env,[instantiates(buffer)],[],[]),
```

it works but every time I re-consult the file it barks an error because the object already exists.

Is there a way to check if the object already exists and skip recreating it ?

---

more code:

```
:- use_module(library(logtalk)).

:- consult(utils).

%% :- initialization((
%%     logtalk_load([buffer,env]).
%% )).
:- {buffer}.
:- initialization(main).

main :-
    %% create_object(env,[instantiates(buffer)],[],[]), 
    env::set(uid,0), env::set(name,"").
```

---

this worked :

```
:- initialization((
    logtalk_load([buffer])
)).
```

i.e. no dot and no "env"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `current_object/1` predicate to check if an object exists. But from your code fragment is seems that you could simply define the `env` object in a source file. If you need `env` to be a dynamic object (why?), then use the `dynamic/0` directive:

```
:- object(env,
    instantiates(buffer)).

    :- (dynamic)/0.

:- end_object
```

Btw, never use top-level abbreviations (such as `{}/1`) in source files; they are not part of the language. Write instead:

```
:- use_module(library(logtalk)).
:- initialization((
    logtalk_load([buffer, env])
)).
```

P.S. You're using the `logtalk` pack for SWI-Prolog. But this pack meant for  *deployment*, not *development*, as it hides all files on the Logtalk distribution (including documentation) inside the hidden directory used for packs.

Comment: i have other stuff in "main"

Comment: Note that you can have multiple `initialization/1` directives in the same source file.

Comment: i had env in buffer.lgt but i thought it will be  better in the source file. may be u are right i dont need it in the source cause it is not dynamic

Comment: whats the benefit of not using pack ?

Comment: {buffer} works the other doesnt.... i'm using env in main

Comment: How are you using the `env` object in `main/0`? What errors do you get? Can you expand the question with those details?

Comment: There's nothing in your edited code that would trigger an error when using an `initialization /1` directive to load the files. The initialization goals are run in order. Thus, by the time you call `main/0`, the `buffer` and `env` source files are already loaded. If you're getting any error or warning with my suggestion, add it to your question to clarify.

Comment: i put env in buffer not as separate file ;)

Comment: The dot as a typo indeed. Fixed. But no reason why having the objects in separate files would cause an error or warning. As far as I understand, `env` depends on `buffer`. so, as long as you load `buffer` before the `env`, you should get a clean compilation.